# Existence proof of Bourbaki, Differentiable and Analytic Manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

I am reading through Chapter III of Bourbaki, *Lie Groups and Lie Algebras*, and many proofs cite the Bourbaki volume *Differentiable and Analytic Manifolds*.  I can't find this book anywhere.  Does it actually exist?

Comment: It certainly exists: MR0219078 (36 #2161) Bourbaki, N.
Éléments de mathématique. Fasc. XXXIII. Variétés différentielles et analytiques. Fascicule de résultats (Paragraphes 1 à 7). (French)
Actualités Scientifiques et Industrielles, No. 1333 Hermann, Paris 1967 97 pp.

Comment: Serre's book *Lie algebras and Lie groups* also covers (somewhat from scratch) a fair amount of the relevant material from that Bourbaki book.

Comment: The reference given by @IgorBelegradek is sound (ISBN- 13 978-3-540-34396-7) it is a summary and not a complete exposition. Up to my knowledge, this was never translated to English nor expanded as a worked out text.

Comment: @D_S: A PDF version is available here: https://libgen.pw/view.php?id=339015

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This book exists of course, it is even translated into Russian (as all Bourbaki books are), and it is easy to find in Russian. I have it. However this book is only a
"Fascicule de résultats", which means that it is a sort of resume (definitions and statements without proofs) of a much larger book which does not exist (the complete book was never written).

(They say that when Grothendieck joined the project, he started to insists on his own ideas what this book should contain and how it should be written, which killed the whole project of the planned "Cours d'Analyse".)